# Get most active friends in chat using Facebook FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get what are the most active friends in chat via FQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `count()` method in FQL, so no, not directly. You could query the [thread](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/thread/) table and then loop through the `recipients` returned to count it in your own script.

If you look at the new [unified_message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message/) and related tables in the documentation, it appears that Facebook is adding features to the messaging system. You may be able to do this in the future.